# How does Scala's .min avoid the penalty of boxing and unboxing?

Tags: performance, scala, boxing

`Vector.min` is [implemented](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/cdd9845a5eabacb972abdcb1fb5975a45ea4fab9/src/library/scala/collection/TraversableOnce.scala#L191) as

```
def min[B >: A](implicit cmp: Ordering[B]): A = {
  if (isEmpty)
    throw new UnsupportedOperationException("empty.min")
  reduceLeft((x, y) => if (cmp.lteq(x, y)) x else y)
}
```

and when you profile

```
Vector.fill(1000000)(scala.util.Random.nextLong).min
```

it's fast and there's no boxing or unboxing going on. If, however, you write the apparently equivalent

```
val cmp = implicitly[Ordering[Long]]
Vector.fill(1000000)(scala.util.Random.nextLong).reduceLeft((x, y) => if (cmp.lteq(x, y)) x else y)
```

it runs approximately 10 times slower (ignoring the time in Random, which otherwise dominates this, and yes, I warmed my benchmarks up...).

> How is the first version avoiding the performance penalty of the boxing?

**Edit:** here's my profiling code:

```
val cmp = implicitly[Ordering[Long]]

def randomLongs = Vector.fill(1000000)(scala.util.Random.nextLong)

def timing[R](f: => R): (Long, R) = {
  val startTime = System.nanoTime
  val result = f
  ((System.nanoTime - startTime) / 1000000, result)
}

def minTiming = { val r = randomLongs; timing(r.min)._1 }
def reduceLeftTiming = { val r = randomLongs; timing(r.reduceLeft((x, y) => if (cmp.lteq(x, y)) x else y))._1 }

while(true) {
  println((minTiming, reduceLeftTiming))
}
```

and I see times using `min` of around 20ms, using `reduceLeft` of ~200ms. I've profiled this code using `YourKit`; here's a [screen grab](http://static.inky.ws/image/2037/image.jpg) of the call tree showing that `min` doesn't result in any boxing.

Comment: Sorry, I have no time to check myself right now, but apparently, you use `reduce` in your own implementation instead of `reduceLeft`. Could it account for the slowdown ?

Comment: "there is no boxing or unboxing going on" - how have you come to this conclusion (as I don't believe it)

Comment: @paradigmatic, oops, fixed, doesn't affect what I'm seeing.

Comment: What if you use `val cmp = implicitly[Ordering[java.util.Long]]` instead? Does this affect the time?

Comment: @oxbow_lakes, I've included my profiling code, and a screen grab from YourKit showing `reduceLeft` boxing, and `min` not.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov, I think you've got it. I needed both 
`val cmp = implicitly[Ordering[java.lang.Long]]`
and
`def randomLongs: Vector[java.lang.Long] = Vector.fill(1000000)(scala.util.Random.nextLong)`, but with those they become equally fast.

Comment: (If you feel like answering I'll happily accept it.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think the first version infers `java.lang.Long` for `B`. So there still is boxing going on, but only while filling the vector, and afterwards all comparisons are between boxed objects.

In the second version, since type of `cmp` is given as `Ordering[Long]`, `java.lang.Long`s in the vector have to be unboxed before being passed to `cmp.lteq(x, y)`.